# ImageView is crashing app

Tags: android, imageview

In one of my layouts, I have a textView and an imageView. The textView works fine, but when I add the imageView, the app does some weird crap when that layout is called (When it's called, the app freezes for a few seconds, then the screen goes black for a while, then the app gets put in the background).

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@drawable/background">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#87cefa"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="Some Text"
        android:gravity="center"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/splashscreen"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

I know it's the imageview because if I take it away, all goes well. Thanks in advance!!

Logcat: `08-13 19:37:13.483: E/Trace(23530): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)

08-13 19:37:13.803: E/SensorManager(23530): thread start

08-13 19:37:14.103: E/(23530): <s3dReadConfigFile:75>: Can't open file for reading

08-13 19:37:14.103: E/(23530): <s3dReadConfigFile:75>: Can't open file for reading

08-13 19:37:24.524: E/dalvikvm(23530): Fatal spin-on-suspend, dumping threads

08-13 19:37:24.574: E/dalvikvm(23530): threadid=1: stuck on threadid=12, giving up

08-13 19:37:24.574: A/libc(23530): Fatal signal 16 (SIGSTKFLT) at 0x00005bea (code=-6), thread 23549 (Thread-946)`

Comment: Logcat says that file you provided is not exist.

Comment: Logcat is talkin about trace file not being present..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have given fill_parent for imageview. It will try to cover the complete screen. It will even overlap textview. try to give wrap_content. Or try to put a fixed size. Or try weight. Else try for relative layout.

Comment: That's not true, fill_parent will make it fill the parent going down from where it started. And the other ideas didn't work, thanks though.

Comment: Is your splash screen image of large size? You say the app freezes ffor some time. May be UI thread is getting blocked while trying to decode image and finally crashes as its longer time to decode.

Comment: That's it^ It was too big